# Need help in flowplayer playlist

Tags: php, jquery, flowplayer, playlist

In my current project, I have to add a video player with a playlist. I am using flowplayer. After the first video plays, I need to play the second video like a real playlist. Following is my source code:

```
$(function() {
$(".entries").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    visible: 3,
    circular: true,
    speed: 10
});

$f("player", "<?php echo $path ?>swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
    plugins: {
        controls: {
            playlist: true,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            backgroundGradient: 'none',
            bottom: '1',
        }
    },
    clip: { 
            baseUrl: 'http://localhost/hurltv/uploads/videos/', 
            autoPlay:false, 
            autoBuffering:true
        }
}).playlist("div.entries:first", {loop:true});
```

});

The playlist is working except the videos are not continuesly playing one after the other. Can anybody help me to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace "div.entries:first" with "div.entries"?

Comment: I've added div.entries to make the playlist start from the anchor which has the class name first, so once the first video has played the rest of the things will be played automatically